# Compute the following summation

Tags: integration, summation

Compute $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{5^n k!}}}$$
My approach: $$\int_{\mathbb{N}}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{5^n k!}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\int_{\mathbb{N}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{5^n k!}}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^n}{\int_{\mathbb{N}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{k!}}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{5^n}}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{ k!}}}$$
I'm stuck here, can somebody show how can I proceed from here or how can I tackle this from another approach? Thanks.

Comment: What does exactly mean $\int_{\mathbb{N}}$?

Answer (score 5):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+k} n^k}{5^n k!} &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{5^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} n^k}{ k!} \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{5^n} e^{-n} \\
&=& \frac{1}{1+1/(5e)} = \frac{5e}{1+5e}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How do you justify the separation of the series?

Comment: The order of the series being inverted can be justified by their convergence.

Comment: Thank you! $$ $$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I don't understand how did you transform the summation of the k-dependent values to $e^{-n}$?

Comment: Power series for the exponential function ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^x=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{m!}
\end{eqnarray*} $x=(-n)$

Comment: Well what about $(-1)^k$?

Comment: $(-1)^k n^k = (-n)^k$.